# Scoping and script loading

Tags: javascript, scope

I'm trying to build a rather simple javascript loader mechanism of my own. I know there are plenty of libs out there doing this better, but I thought I could learn something by trying out for myself.

Below is my (simplified) code. My aim is to keep the references to all different js files (the mods) in one place, the `_Mods` object. When a script tag has loaded, it will send a custom event that the code listens to, with its own mod data (from the `_Mods` object) as a parameter. Every time when receiving that custom event, the plan was to flag that mod as loaded, and eventually state that all mods have loaded. And then proceed.

My problem is, when I run this code the console will print `mod 'word' loaded!` once and then exit. If I comment out the `!mod.callback.done` condition before running `callback()` it will print `mod 'word' loaded!` three times.

Thus, I realize that the `mod` variable gets reassigned for every new mod that should be loaded, and at the time the script is loaded and should do its callback, the pointers to the first two mods' data objects are lost.

Any suggestions how I could refactor this in order to get callbacks from the three *different* mods?

```
(function(window) {
    var ModLoader = (function() {
        var _Mods = {
            game: {
                name: "game",
                src: "js/GameEngine.js"
            },
            dictionary: {
                name: "dictionary",
                src: "js/Dictionary.js"
            },
            word: {
                name: "word",
                src: "js/Word.js"
            }
        },

        _loadMods = function() {
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD').item(0);
            for (var property in _Mods) {
                if (_Mods.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                    var mod = _Mods[property],
                        scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
                    scriptTag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
                    scriptTag.src = mod.src;

                    mod.callback = function() {
                        var customEvent = document.createEvent("Events");
                        customEvent.initEvent("ModLoaded", true, true);
                        customEvent.mod = mod;
                        window.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
                    };

                    scriptTag.onreadystatechange = scriptTag.onload = function() {
                        var state = scriptTag.readyState;
                        if (!mod.callback.done && (!state || /loaded|complete/.test(state))) {
                            mod.callback.done = true;
                            mod.callback();
                        }
                    };

                    (document.body || head).appendChild(scriptTag);    
                }
            }
        },

        _modLoaded = function(event) {
            console.log("mod '" + event.mod.name + "' loaded!");
        };

        return {
            loadMods: _loadMods,
            modLoaded: _modLoaded
        };
    })();

    window.addEventListener("ModLoaded", ModLoader.modLoaded, false);

    ModLoader.loadMods();

})(window);
```

Comment: maybe you'll need function bind to bind mod as argument, otherwise it's a closure and will reference the last mod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
scriptTag.onreadystatechange = scriptTag.onload = (function(mod) {
    return function(){
        var state = scriptTag.readyState;
        if (!mod.callback.done && (!state || /loaded|complete/.test(state))) {
            mod.callback.done = true;
            mod.callback();
        }
    };
})(mod);
```

Comment: Well, at least you pointed me in the right direction. Your code was erroneous, but if you remove the return row and the very last row it did work. Update your answer, and I'll mark it as a working solution.

Comment: Heh. Instead of returning a function, just execute the code within it. Then it works for me.

Comment: What will happen if you keep the return? I've edited my code, so it should be fine now.

Comment: That's the thing. WITH the return, nothing ever happens. WITHOUT the return though, everything works hunky-dory.

Comment: The returned function would have to be self-executing in order to make it work. Now it's just returned, but never called.

Comment: ok...actually I don't quite understand your code, but since you mentioned the first two mod got lost, I figured it might have something to do with the closure...anyway as long as it works now, I don't care it's marked as right anwser or not :)